# Angular - Monorepo with pre-built plugins

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx

These are the current versions of my monorepository workspace that I'm working with:

```
> node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@nrwl/cli/bin/nx "version"


     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 10.0.2
Node: 12.16.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 10.0.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.901.11
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.1000.2
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr   0.1000.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.901.11
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.901.11
@angular-devkit/core               9.1.11
@angular-devkit/schematics         10.0.2
@angular/cdk                       10.0.2
@angular/cli                       10.0.2
@angular/flex-layout               10.0.0-beta.32
@angular/material                  10.0.2
@angular/material-moment-adapter   10.0.2
@ngtools/webpack                   9.1.11
@schematics/angular                10.0.2
@schematics/update                 0.1000.2
ng-packagr                         10.0.1
rxjs                               6.6.0
typescript                         3.9.6
webpack                            4.42.0
```

I'm currently struggling with a monorepository setup that provides a "plugin"-framework.
Shortly described: we use a @nrwl/nx workspace to manage the whole codebase, and the structure looks somewhat like this:

```
apps/web-ui
apps/mobile-ui
libs/core *
libs/shared *
libs/layout *
libs/feature1
libs/feature2
libs/feature3
```

The libraries marked with * are publishable, built with ng-packagr regularly and pushed to our private npm registry.

---

Besides our monorepository workspace, there is a second project, our sandbox. It should allow external companies to develop "plugins" for our apps of the main-project without having to checkout the workspace (and thus getting in control of our full codebase), but still be able to use our core and shared components. They just have to implement some interfaces of our core library and should also be able to use our shared components. Only this way we can control number and date formatting, display of common domain objects, etc.

So, I created a 2nd nx-workspace and installed the pre-built packages from our private npm registry. External developers can now create some new modules and components based on our core, shared and layout libraries. As soon as they are finished, they should just package their libraries (of course without bundling our libraries into the build result and just declaring them as peer dependency!) and publish them back to our npm registry.

---

Based on our decision, we want to pull in the finished modules. Doing so fails unfortunately, because Ivy tries to compile the `node_modules/@external1/plugin1` with `ngcc` and inside of our workspace the libraries are, of course, not pre-built but rather available as source code in the libs-folder and used via path-mapping. I can't even change this, because it would break live reload capabilities (and additionally, it didn't work with pre-built libraries anyway (changing the path-mappings in tsconfig.json from `libs/core/src/lib/index.ts` to `dist/libs/core` etc.). Besides that we would have to delete the ivy_ngcc folder inside `node_modules/@external/@plugin1` on every recompile of the libraries, otherwise they would be linked wrong either way, if I understood correctly?

I found some tickets on github that describe my issue:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/33659, https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/29361 (<-- this one describes it best), https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/33562, https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/1189

But none of them helped me out of the compilation problem.

Currently the output of ng serve looks like this:

```
ERROR in Failed to compile entry-point @external1/plugin1/shared (es2015 as esm2015) due to compilation errors:
node_modules/@external1/plugin1/fesm2015/plugin1-shared.js:176:29 - error NG2005: The class 'NumberPipe' cannot be created via dependency injection, as it does not have an Angular decorator. This will result in an error at runtime.

Either add the @Injectable() decorator to 'NumberPipe', or configure a different provider (such as a provider with 'useFactory').


176                 providers: [NumberPipe, CwaDatePipe],
                                ~~~~~~~~~~

  libs/core/src/lib/shared/pipes/number.pipe.ts:16:1
     16 @Pipe({
        ~~~~~~~
     17   name: 'cwaNumber',
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ...
     31   }
        ~~~
     32 }
        ~
    'NumberPipe' is declared here.
node_modules/@external1/plugin1/fesm2015/plugin1-shared.js:176:41 - error NG2005: The class 'CwaDatePipe' cannot be created via dependency injection, as it does not have an Angular decorator. This will result in an error at runtime.

Either add the @Injectable() decorator to 'CwaDatePipe', or configure a different provider (such as a provider with 'useFactory').


176                 providers: [NumberPipe, CwaDatePipe],
                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Before the upgrade to angular@10, using angular@9.0.7 I got the "Unable to write a reference" error, similar to https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/29361.

---

Does anyone have a better idea for my setup or knows, how to fix the compilation failures?
I'm not sure if my approach is correct and this is a valid setup, but I really don't know a better way to achieve this.

Thanks in adance!